# OpenLayers 4.6.5 - jQuery : map disappears after hide() show() event

Tags: openlayers, jquery, tab

This is a little example of what I'm trying to do : https://codepen.io/remifroger/pen/ZZWgbM

I would like to build a tabs design, with one map in each tab. I use jQuery to deal with it but I have a trouble when I resize the window.

I already tested to use map.updateSize() in each click event but it doesn't work, do you have any ideas to fix this behavior ?

**EDIT**

Problem comes from the `hide()` method which applies a `display: none` on a parent element of my div containing the map => it also affects a `display: none` on the map div's; and this generates the unwanted behaviors

So to fix the problem, instead of show() and hide() methods, I use the visibility property (with jQuery : `$("#id").css('visibility', '...')`) which doesn't generate any `display: none`

And I put the content of the tab content in `position: absolute` to eliminate spaces

I updated the CodePen, but I'm still open to any improvement, this method doesn't seem optimal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `map.setTarget(none)` before your `.hide()`method and then `map.setTarget(yourMapContainer)` and `map.updateSize()` after your `.show()` method.